# Object storing and retrieving using wildcard identifier

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, template, stl

I'm writing an interpreter for a scripting language which allows objects to:

- Have an alias
- Be referenced using a wildcard
- Contain child objects
- Combination of all three above

For example:

```
CreateWindow("win", ...);
CreateName("win/texes1", ...);
CreateName("win/texes2", ...);
CreateAlias("win/texes1", "wintexes");
CreateAlias("win/texes2", "wintexes2");
CreateTexture("@wintexes/tex1", ...);
CreateTexture("@wintexes/tex2", ...);
Delete("@wintexes/*"); // Deletes textures
Delete("@wintexes*"); // Deletes names
Delete("win");
```

Crazy, I know. It wasn't me who came up with it though.

In order to call the function on all objects intended to be affected by it, I came up with this code:

```
class ObjectHolder_t : private Holder<Object>
{
public:
    virtual ~ObjectHolder_t()
    {
    }

    Object* Read(const string& Handle)
    {
        string Leftover = Handle;
        string ObjHandle = ExtractObjHandle(Leftover);
        if (Leftover.empty())
            return Holder::Read(ObjHandle);
        return GetHolder(ObjHandle)->Read(Leftover);
    }

    void Write(const string& Handle, Object* pObject)
    {
        string Leftover = Handle;
        string ObjHandle = ExtractObjHandle(Leftover);
        if (Leftover.empty())
            Holder::Write(ObjHandle, pObject);
        else
            GetHolder(ObjHandle)->Write(Leftover, pObject);
    }

    template <class F>
    void Execute(const string& Handle, F Func)
    {
        string Leftover = Handle;
        string ObjHandle = ExtractObjHandle(Leftover);
        if (ObjHandle.back() == '*')
            ObjHandle.front() == '@' ? WildcardAlias(Leftover, ObjHandle, Func) : WildcardCache(Leftover, ObjHandle, Func);
        else
            Leftover.empty() ? Func(&Cache.find(ObjHandle)->second) : GetHolder(ObjHandle)->Execute(Leftover, Func);
    }

    void WriteAlias(const string& Handle, const string& Alias)
    {
        Aliases[Alias] = Handle;
    }

private:
    template <class F>
    void ExecuteSafe(const string& HolderHandle, const string& Handle, F Func)
    {
        if (ObjectHolder_t* pHolder = GetHolder(HolderHandle))
            pHolder->Execute(Handle, Func);
    }

    template <class F>
    void WildcardAlias(const string& Leftover, const string& ObjHandle, F Func)
    {
        std::regex Regex(Regexify(ObjHandle.substr(1)));
        for (auto i = Aliases.begin(); i != Aliases.end(); ++i)
            if (std::regex_match(i->first, Regex))
                Leftover.empty() ? Execute(i->second, Func) : ExecuteSafe(i->second, Leftover, Func);
    }

    template <class F>
    void WildcardCache(const string& Leftover, const string& ObjHandle, F Func)
    {
        std::regex Regex(Regexify(ObjHandle));
        for (auto i = Cache.begin(); i != Cache.end(); ++i)
            if (std::regex_match(i->first, Regex))
                Leftover.empty() ? Func(&i->second) : ExecuteSafe(i->first, Leftover, Func);
    }

    string Regexify(const string& Wildcard)
    {
        return string("^" + Wildcard.substr(0, Wildcard.size() - 1) + ".*");
    }

    string ExtractObjHandle(string& Handle)
    {
        // Name
        string ObjHandle;
        size_t Index = Handle.find('/');
        if (Index != string::npos)
        {
            ObjHandle = Handle.substr(0, Index);
            Handle = Handle.substr(Index + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            ObjHandle = Handle;
            Handle.clear();
        }
        // Alias
        if (ObjHandle.front() == '@' && ObjHandle.back() != '*')
        {
            Handle = Aliases[ObjHandle.substr(1)] + "/" + Handle;
            ObjHandle = ExtractObjHandle(Handle);
        }
        return ObjHandle;
    }

    ObjectHolder_t* GetHolder(const string& Handle)
    {
        return (ObjectHolder_t*)(Holder::Read(Handle));
    }

    map<string, string> Aliases;
};
```

Variable name `Cache` is a bit misleading here, but that's what I get for reusing `Holder<T>` which was intended for another purpose. `Cache` is actually `std::map<std::string, Object*>`.

```
struct MapDeleter
{
    template <class T> void operator() (T Data) { delete Data.second; }
};

template <class T>
struct Holder
{
    ~Holder()
    {
        for_each(Cache.begin(), Cache.end(), MapDeleter());
    }

    T* Read(const string& Path)
    {
        auto iter = Cache.find(Path);
        if (iter != Cache.end())
            return iter->second;
        return nullptr;
    }

    void Write(const string& Path, T* Data)
    {
        Cache[Path] = Data;
    }

    map<string, T*> Cache;
};
```

The code is used like this:

```
void NSBInterpreter::Move()
{
    string Handle = PopString();
    int32_t Time = PopInt();
    int32_t X = PopInt();
    int32_t Y = PopInt();
    /*int32_t Tempo = */PopInt();
    bool Wait = PopBool();

    ObjectHolder.Execute(Handle, [Time, X, Y] (Object** ppObject)
    {
        if (Texture* pTexture = dynamic_cast<Texture*>(*ppObject))
            pTexture->Move(Time, X, Y);
    });

    if (Wait)
        pContext->Wait(Time);
}
```

My concern with this code is that it is very complex and spaghetti recursive (although recursion isn't very deep so it won't crash) and I will probably forget how exactly it works by the time it needs fixing. Any thoughts on improving this?

Comment: Where are the functions `CreateWindow`, `CreateName`, etc.?

Comment: They don't do anything special. CreateWindow/Name are basically `ObjectHolder.Write(Handle, pWindow);` and SetAlias is `ObjectHolder.WriteAlias(Handle, PopString());`

Comment: You might consider protecting `ObjHandle.back()=='*'`. It's illegal if `ObjHandle` is empty and it appears to be accessed at the entry point of this module. Even if there's protection elsewhere I would always recommend guarding the entry point. The behavior of accessing an empty string could be catastrophic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer-length response to [Mislav's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71953/object-storing-and-retrieving-using-wildcard-identifier/80621#comment147854_80621), which asked two questions.

> I'm not sure how is (13) supposed to work. One way would be to construct a list of objects and return it, but I guess that's not very efficient.

To be able to write

```
for (Object *pObject : ObjectHolder.Write(Handle)) {
   ...
}
```

we need to make `ObjectHolder_t::Write()` return an object with `begin()` and `end()` methods, which when called return *iterator objects* (implementing `operator*` and `operator++`) that do the right thing in context. That is, something like

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <regex>
#include <type_traits>

template<class Iter>
struct IterPair {
    Iter b_, e_;
    IterPair(Iter b, Iter e): b_(std::move(b)), e_(std::move(e)) {}
    Iter begin() const { return b_; }
    Iter end() const { return e_; }
};

template<class T>
struct Holder {
    using ptr_t = std::unique_ptr<T>;
    using cache_t = std::map<std::string, ptr_t>;
    cache_t cache_;

    template<bool WritingAllowed>
    class Iterator {
        using star_t = typename std::conditional<WritingAllowed, ptr_t, const ptr_t>::type;
        using ctor_t = typename std::conditional<WritingAllowed, cache_t, const cache_t>::type;
        using cur_t = typename std::conditional<WritingAllowed, typename cache_t::iterator, typename cache_t::const_iterator>::type;
        friend class Holder<T>;
        cur_t cur_, end_;
        std::regex rx_;
        explicit Iterator(ctor_t& map) : cur_(map.end()), end_(map.end()) {}
        explicit Iterator(ctor_t& map, std::regex rx) : cur_(map.begin()), end_(map.end()), rx_(std::move(rx)) {
            while (cur_ != end_ && !std::regex_match(cur_->first, rx_)) {
                ++cur_;
            }
        }
    public:
        star_t& operator*() const {
            return cur_->second;
        }
        Iterator& operator++() {
            do {
                ++cur_;
            } while (cur_ != end_ && !std::regex_match(cur_->first, rx_));
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) const { return cur_ == rhs.cur_; }
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) const { return cur_ != rhs.cur_; }
    };

    // for pedagogical purposes only
    Holder() {
        cache_.insert(std::make_pair("alpha", std::make_unique<int>(1)));
        cache_.insert(std::make_pair("beta", std::make_unique<int>(2)));
        cache_.insert(std::make_pair("gamma", std::make_unique<int>(3)));
        cache_.insert(std::make_pair("delta", std::make_unique<int>(4)));
    }

    IterPair<Iterator<false>> Read(const std::regex& path_regex) const {
        using Iter = Iterator<false>;
        return { Iter(cache_, path_regex), Iter(cache_) };
    }

    IterPair<Iterator<true>> Write(const std::regex& path_regex) {
        using Iter = Iterator<true>;
        return { Iter(cache_, path_regex), Iter(cache_) };
    }
};

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    Holder<int> h;

    for (const std::unique_ptr<int>& pi : h.Read(std::regex(".*ta"))) {
        printf("%d\n", *pi);
    }
}
```

Remove the `const` in `main()` to see what kind of compiler error you get if you try to write to the result of a `Read()` call.

> Another problem is that one specific Func is supposed to be able to delete the object...

I think you'll find that the iterator design removes this problem entirely:

```
void NSBInterpreter::Delete() {
    std::string Handle = PopString();

    for (std::unique_ptr<Object>& pObj : ObjectHolder.Write(Handle)) {
        if (NSBContext* pThread = dynamic_cast<NSBContext*>(pObj.get())) {
            RemoveThread(pThread);
        }
        pObj = nullptr;
    }
}
```

However, using your original "visitor" design, I would observe that the operation "delete this object" needs to be *managed* by the ObjectHolder itself, and therefore I would tend to implement the operation via a *"manager" object* passed in to the visitor function.

```
void NSBInterpreter::Delete() {
    std::string Handle = PopString();

    ObjectHolder.Execute(Handle, [this](Object** ppObject, ObjectHolder_t::Manager& mgr) {
        if (NSBContext* pThread = dynamic_cast<NSBContext*>(*ppObject)) {
            RemoveThread(pThread);
        }
        mgr.Delete(ppObject);  // or perhaps just mgr.DeleteCurrentObject();
    });
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile for me (neither with gcc nor clang with --std=c++1y). Iterator ctor expects non-const reference to cache_t but a const one is passed since Holder::Read is const. I'm not sure how to fix that properly. But anyway I really like that design.

Comment: That'll teach me to add `const` to the `Read` method right before posting the code! There are three possible fixes: (1) drop the `const` from `Read` again, (2) cast away the `const` inside `Iterator`'s constructor, or (3) add a bunch of `std::conditional`s to make the types all line up. I did #3 above, just to prove that it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

The code is a bit verbose, which makes it hard to review in a tiny StackOverflow window... but here are my thoughts. I'll start with the nitpicks and then see about bigger issues.

(1) You use unadorned `string` and `map`, which means you're relying on `using namespace std;`. Don't do that. It's Just Not Done in typical C++ code.

(2) `ObjectHolder_t` has a virtual destructor, which is nice, but it already inherits from `Holder<T>`, whose destructor *isn't* virtual. (It's `private` inheritance, so I guess that's sort-of okay... but again it's bad style. It sends up red flags for the reader (me), which wastes my time even if they're false alarms.)

Also, speaking of the verbosity of this code, it's good style to put those empty braces on a single line instead of spread over three lines. Use `virtual ~Holder() {}` or `virtual ~Holder() = default;`, and remove the now-redundant destructor from `ObjectHolder_t`.

(3) `std::map` is a code smell; code using it can usually be optimized by replacing it with `std::unordered_map`. Unless of course your algorithm *requires* that the map be sorted, in which case, I'd add a `// comment` explaining that, right at the point where the reader is going to be smelling that `std::map`.

(4) `ExtractObjHandle` mutates its argument, in addition to returning another string by value. That's a big smelly code smell, and indeed we can see that the one place you use this subroutine (in `Read`, `Write`, and `Execute`), you have to explicitly copy the argument string because you don't want the original to be mutated. The proper way to return a pair of strings from a method is to change the return type to `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`. At that point you can also consider changing the parameter type from `const std::string&` to `std::string` if it would eliminate an explicit copy operation.

(5) That `MapDeleter` cruft seems like a buggy reimplementation of `std::unique_ptr`: you're just looking for something that holds a pointer and deletes it when it's destroyed. You can safely make the substitution.

(6) In fact, this whole "cache" thing is a bit boned from the start, because the `Read` method allows a pointer to "escape" from the cache's map. The caller could store that pointer somewhere, and then the cache gets destroyed (via `~Holder`), which destroys the pointed-to object... and you end up with undefined behavior the next time you try to access the object through the original pointer. To fix this, the textbook approach is to use `std::shared_ptr` to manage lifetimes, and the real-world approach is "don't do that then". I'll assume your code doesn't do that, and that returning raw pointers to managed objects is totally fine by you.

(7) Nitpick: `const`ify your const methods.

(8) Another nitpick: prefer `Handle.npos` to `std::string::npos`; it's just one fewer thing to worry about whether you matched up the types correctly. Modern C++ is quickly moving in the direction of "generic programming", which in a nutshell means never having to explicitly write out your data types if you don't need to. See also Herb Sutter's concept of "**A**lmost **A**lways **A**uto".

(9) In `Regexify`, you `return string(...);` where `...` represents an expression of type `string`. The correct idiom here is simply `return ...;`. The former means "Evaluate `...`, move-construct another `string` from it, and then move-construct the return value from that string." (The last move-construction may be [elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).) As opposed to `return ...;`, which means "Evaluate `...`, and then move-construct the return value from it." (The last move-construction may be elided.)

So let's see, what are we left with...?

```
template <class T> struct Holder
{
    T* Read(const std::string& Path) const {
        auto iter = Cache.find(Path);
        return iter == Cache.end() ? nullptr : iter->second.get();
    }

    void Write(const std::string& Path, T* Data) {
        Cache[Path] = std::unique_ptr<T>(Data);
    }

    virtual ~Holder() = default;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<T>> Cache;
};

class ObjectHolder_t : private Holder<Object>
{
public:
    Object* Read(const std::string& Handle) {
        std::string ObjHandle, Leftover;
        std::tie(ObjHandle, Leftover) = ExtractObjHandle(Handle);
        if (Leftover.empty())
            return Holder::Read(ObjHandle);
        return GetHolder(ObjHandle)->Read(Leftover);
    }

    void Write(const string& Handle, Object* pObject) {
        std::string ObjHandle, Leftover;
        std::tie(ObjHandle, Leftover) = ExtractObjHandle(Handle);
        if (Leftover.empty())
            Holder::Write(ObjHandle, pObject);
        else
            GetHolder(ObjHandle)->Write(Leftover, pObject);
    }

    template <class F>
    void Execute(const string& Handle, F Func) {
        std::string ObjHandle, Leftover;
        std::tie(ObjHandle, Leftover) = ExtractObjHandle(Handle);
        if (ObjHandle.back() == '*') {
            ObjHandle.front() == '@' ? WildcardAlias(Leftover, ObjHandle, Func) : WildcardCache(Leftover, ObjHandle, Func);
        } else {
            Leftover.empty() ? Func(&Cache.find(ObjHandle)->second) : GetHolder(ObjHandle)->Execute(Leftover, Func);
        }
    }

    void WriteAlias(const std::string& Handle, const std::string& Alias) {
        Aliases[Alias] = Handle;
    }

private:
    template <class F>
    void ExecuteSafe(const string& HolderHandle, const string& Handle, F Func)
    {
        if (ObjectHolder_t* pHolder = GetHolder(HolderHandle))
            pHolder->Execute(Handle, Func);
    }

    template <class F>
    void WildcardAlias(const string& Leftover, const string& ObjHandle, F Func)
    {
        std::regex Regex(Regexify(ObjHandle.substr(1)));
        for (auto i = Aliases.begin(); i != Aliases.end(); ++i)
            if (std::regex_match(i->first, Regex))
                Leftover.empty() ? Execute(i->second, Func) : ExecuteSafe(i->second, Leftover, Func);
    }

    template <class F>
    void WildcardCache(const string& Leftover, const string& ObjHandle, F Func)
    {
        std::regex Regex(Regexify(ObjHandle));
        for (auto i = Cache.begin(); i != Cache.end(); ++i)
            if (std::regex_match(i->first, Regex))
                Leftover.empty() ? Func(&i->second) : ExecuteSafe(i->first, Leftover, Func);
    }

    std::string Regexify(const std::string& Wildcard)
    {
        return "^" + Wildcard.substr(0, Wildcard.size() - 1) + ".*";
    }

    std::pair<std::string, std::string> ExtractObjHandle(const std::string& Handle)
    {
        std::pair<std::string, std::string> Result;
        size_t Index = Handle.find('/');
        if (Index != Handle.npos) {
            Result.first = Handle.substr(0, Index);
            Result.second = Handle.substr(Index + 1);
        } else {
            Result.first = Handle;
            Result.second.clear();
        }
        std::string& ObjHandle = Result.first;
        if (ObjHandle.front() == '@' && ObjHandle.back() != '*') {
            Result.second = Aliases[ObjHandle.substr(1)] + "/" + Result.second;
            ObjHandle = ExtractObjHandle(Result.second);
        }
        return Result;
    }

    ObjectHolder_t* GetHolder(const std::string& Handle)
    {
        return (ObjectHolder_t*)(Holder::Read(Handle));
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> Aliases;
};
```

...I didn't get all the way through the code, but hopefully this gives you some ideas and maybe I'll do a second round later.

Parting thoughts:

(10) What if function `F` throws an exception – what guarantees does your code provide?

(11) What is function `F` supposed to look like, anyway? A block comment explaining the expected input would be nice. (You should be aware of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), but there are perfectly valid reasons not to use it in a lot of code. *Cough* efficiency *cough*.)

(12) The expression `Func(&Cache.find(ObjHandle)->second)` sends up red flags: what would happen if `ObjHandle` weren't in the `Cache`? What if `Cache.find(ObjHandle)` returned `nullptr`? Et cetera. I'd prefer to see such a complicated raw-pointery expression broken down into simple steps, with each step checked for failure before proceeding to the next step.

(13) A major architectural suggestion: Consider trying a complete rewrite, where instead of passing `F Func` all the way down the stack, you instead make `Read` and `Write` return *pairs of iterators* `begin, end` so that your existing caller

```
ObjectHolder.Execute(Handle, [Time, X, Y] (Object** ppObject)
{
    if (Texture* pTexture = dynamic_cast<Texture*>(*ppObject))
        pTexture->Move(Time, X, Y);
});
```

ends up looking more like

```
for (Object *pObject : ObjectHolder.Write(Handle)) {
    if (Texture *pTexture = dynamic_cast<Texture*>(pObject)) {
        pTexture->Move(Time, X, Y);
    }
}
```

That would be idiomatic C++11 (except for the smelly use of `dynamic_cast`, of course), and it's not significantly harder than what you're doing now. Give it a try and post a comment if you do! :)

Comment: Thanks for the review. I implemented most of the suggestions. However, I'm not sure how is (13) supposed to work. One way would be to construct a list of objects and return it, but I guess that's not very efficient. Another problem is that one specific Func is supposed to be able to delete the object, so I did this: http://paste2.org/_0a4YvC1c
How bad was that idea?